# Pattern quality is missing when object is scaled in Fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I have a fabric object with `fabric.Pattern` (image). when I scale the object, the filled  pattern quality is missing (very poor).

Is there any way to improve the pattern quality when I scale the object?

Is there any way to repeat the pattern when I scale the object?

Answer (score 2):

I think this will solve your problem:

```js
canvas.observe("object:scaling", function (e) {
    var shape = e.target;
    shape.width = shape.scaleX * shape.width;
    shape.height = shape.scaleY * shape.height;
    shape.scaleX = 1;
    shape.scaleY = 1;
});
```

If you are using scaling you can keep `scaleX` and `scaleY` in variables and restore them after resizing (instead of make them `1`).

Comment: This answer do not make sense. width and height will not make anything but a rectangle bigger.